# INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS with two different package names

Tags: android, android-manifest, adb

I have two manifests that I swap round when building different releases of my app. The manifests have different package names yet I can only build one on the device at a time. I really need both to be built. The project has no src files and uses an activity from a library.

Manifest one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.test.pkgone" android:versionCode="01" android:versionName="0.1">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.test.Splashscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Manifest Two:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.test.pkgtwo" android:versionCode="01" android:versionName="0.1">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.test.Splashscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: For a sanity check, I'd `aapt dump badging <your-apk>` for both APKs and ensure that they indeed have different package names... maybe your build process is doing something funky. Also ensure that both apps are uninstalled before you try to install them.

Comment: You seem to have hit the nail on the head! The question is: why is it so? I'm certainly swapping the manifests out. I'm using ant to build in command line.

Comment: Are you sure both are compiling successfully? Maybe you're getting resource not found errors or something and your build process is failing and you're looking at stale APKs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, they're both compiling successfully with no errors from ant and the 'modified' field in windows explorer is updating.

Comment: Hey Roman! Thanks for all your help! I found out that the R.java needed to be cleaned before built! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've sorted it out! The issue was that the R.java file in the gen folder wasn't being cleaned so I just ran

```
ant clean
```

before

```
ant release
```

and it works great! Thanks to @enrmarc and @Roman Nurik for their help :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I had the same problem.
You need to change the "**applicationId**" in your **build.gradle**(Module:app) file

be aware that there will be two build.gradle files. Open the one with (Module:app)

then clean your project.